# ASP.Net FormView Paging Order

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, formview

I have a `FormView` control on which I've enabled paging. It seems to work alright, but what does the control consider to be next/last? Can I control the order in which it pages?

Edit: My data is coming from an Entity Framework object.

Comment: what is your datasource for the `FormView`? DataTable? Generic Collection?  The paging will be based on the datasource and what order the datasource is in

Comment: I'm getting the data from a Entity Framework object that's bound to my database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FormView is connected to some sort of data. The data should be arranged in order that you like. This determines what will be the next/last results.